# How can I solve for two equations who equal each other when I have one unkown using Python?

Tags: python, equation

[image: Image of the equation]

All of the constants are known except for Ts2. I want to iterate for several r2 values, but I also want to know what either side of the equation equals. How would I go about solving something like this in Python?

Small note, not sure it matters but the denominator of the right hand side is supposed to be in the negative 1 power.

I've looked at fsolve in scipy, but don't understand how I would go about writng the code.

Edit: I got an error while I trying this method. Here's my code:

```
def f(ts2, r2):
    e = 0.2
    ts1 = 90
    r1 = 0.25
    o = 5.67 * 10 ** -8
    k = 0.00016
    tsur = 298
    lhand = (ts2 - ts1) / ((1 / (4 * np.pi * k)) * ((1 / r1) - (1 / r2)))
    rhand = (tsur - ts2) / (4 * np.pi * r2 * r2 * (e * o * (ts2 + tsur) * (ts2 * ts2 + tsur * tsur))) ** -1
    return lhand - rhand


rvalues = np.linspace(0.251, 0.3, num=50)
y = np.zeros_like(rvalues)
i = 0

for ele in rvalues:
    y[i] = fsolve(f, 280., args=[ele, ]) # Here it says: Expected type ndarray got float instead.
    i += 1
```

the code in the block is basically the whole program just missing imports and some pyplot lines.
edit: full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/djoha/OneDrive/Dokumenter/Skole/Python/Vår20/Varme/Øving4/1b.py", line 23, in <module>
    y[i] = fsolve(f, 280., args=[ele, ])
  File "C:\Users\djoha\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Skole\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 147, in fsolve
    res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)
  File "C:\Users\djoha\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Skole\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 213, in _root_hybr
    shape, dtype = _check_func('fsolve', 'func', func, x0, args, n, (n,))
  File "C:\Users\djoha\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Skole\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 26, in _check_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
  File "C:/Users/djoha/OneDrive/Dokumenter/Skole/Python/Vår20/Varme/Øving4/1b.py", line 13, in f
    lhand = (ts2 - ts1) / ((1 / (4 * np.pi * k)) * ((1 / r1) - (1 / r2)))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'list'
```

Comment: Please share the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following simplified example:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def f(x):
    return x-1

print(fsolve(f, .5)) # Prints out "[1.]"
```

In this example, there is a function `f(x) = x - 1`. The call to `fsolve` takes this function and a starting point and finds where it equals 0 (Note that I chose a starting point of .5, but you can choose many different starting points and get the same result).

So the answer is to simply rewrite your equation as being equivalent to 0 and use fsolve to solve for `Ts2`.

Edit:

I do not know what default values you want to use for ts1, tsur, etc... but you probably want roughly the following function:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def f(ts2):
    # Define tsur, r2, etc... here!
    lhand = (ts2-ts1)/((1/(4*pi*k))*(1/r1-1/r2))
    rhand = (tsur-ts2)/(4*pi*r2*r2*(e*o*(ts2+tsur)*(ts*ts+tsur*tsur)))**-1
    return lhand-rhand

print(fsolve(f, .5))
```

Edit 2:

If you want to include more parameters, the `fsolve` function accepts the optional argument `args` which takes a list. In this case, I added the extra argument 'y'.

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def f(x, y):
    return x+y

for y in range(10):
    print(fsolve(f, .5, args=[y,]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Only one thing is unclear, how can I iterate for several r2 values? lets say: 
def f(ts2, r2):

How would fsolve work then?

Comment: I've added a second edit that should make that clear.

Comment: Edit: I will put it in the post instead.